# BeautifulSoup4 not working on my hosting server

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use '**BeautifulSoup**' on my hosting server, but without success.

I think I've already successfully installed the module into the server by executing the `python setup,py install --user` command from　`/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/` where I had placed the content of the tar file for installing BeautifulSoup4. However, when I try to import BeautifulSoup on Python, it gave me the following error.

```
from .import _htmlparser
  File "/home/username.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 11, in <module>
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
ImportError: No module named parser
```

I'm also not quite familiar with PYTHONPATH and LIBRARY_PATH, so it would be great if you could give me any tips on exactly what role those two play.

Here are my Python paths:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH $HOME/.locak/lib/python2.7 
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/.local/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

check the [Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```